# How do you convert a MySQL query into an object in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

For example, in Python I have the object "user", which has the attributes "id", "name", "password", and "score". I have a users table in MySQL that has these columns. However, I cannot figure out how to parse the results of a select statement (like "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'FRED') into a python object, so that all of the attributes of Fred's info in the database becomes the attribute of an object. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: We are severely handicapped because you didn't show us any code, but if your MySQL connector is returning rows as dictionaries, you can just do `object.__dict__.update(row)` to copy the row values into the object.

Comment: And, by the way, there are several object/relational mapping modules for Python that can do all of this automatically, so you don't have to write the SQL yourself.

Comment: I suggest you research [pyodbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/). There are numerous examples of how to do exactly what you say you want to do.